# Multinomial Model

Tags: r, multinomial

I am using Multinomial Model to calculate propability of a variable but when I type function  `pmultinom()` in R, it informs could find function, could you help me what packages should I install in R?

Comment: I already installed that package but the same.

Comment: Did you type `library(pmultinom)` at the top of your script and run that line?

Comment: @JasonAizkalns. That second step catches many people .... why couldn't there be just one command to install AND load a library. Something like `instalib()`..